# How to resolve TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str after adding a queue to a threaded function

Tags: python, multithreading

Working in Python 3.4 and given the code below, everything works fine until I add the `mainQ` to the `mainProc` call.  Once I do the threaded calls inside `myFunc` returns the following:

`file1proc = threading.Thread(target=myOtherFunc, args=(rawData['file1']['dataIn'],rawData['file1']['CL'], file1Q), name='file1Thread')
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str`

```
import queue
import threading

def myOtherFunc(someData,someCL,Q)

    output=[somedata,someCL]

    Q.put(output)

def myFunc(rawData, Q):

    file1Q=queue.Queue()
    file2Q=queue.Queue()

    file1proc = threading.Thread(target=myOtherFunc, args=(rawData['file1']['dataIn'],rawData['file1']['CL'], file1Q), name='file1Thread')
    file2proc = threading.Thread(target=myOtherFunc, args=(rawData['file2']['dataIn'],rawData['file2']['CL'], file1Q), name='file1Thread')

    file1proc.start()
    file2proc.start()

    file1proc.join()
    file2proc.join()

    output1=file1Q.get()
    output2=file2Q.get()

    output = [output1, ouput2]

    Q.put(output)


data = {'dataIn': [list1], 'CL': [list2]}

fileData = { 'file1': data, 'file2': data}

mainQ=queue.Queue()

mainProc=threading.Thread(target=myFunc, args=([fileData],mainQ), name="mainProcThread")

mainProc.start()

mainProc.join()

final=mainQ.get()
```

I am not understanding how adding a queue to the arguments is causing the `dicts` to be misunderstood as `lists`.  I know it has to be something simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're putting the `fileData` dict in a list when you pass it to `myFunc`:

```
args=([fileData],mainQ)
```

Then when you try to access the dict via `rawData['file1']` inside  `myFunc`, you're really accessing the list, which can't take the `'file1'` string as an index.

Obviously, you don't want to do that. Do this instead:

```
args=(fileData,mainQ)
```

And the problem should go away. My guess is you originally had this:

```
args=([fileData])
```

Which you thought was putting `fileData` in a tuple, but really was just putting it in a list, which worked ok because the `args` keyword argument expects either a list or tuple.

To actually create a one-element tuple, you'd need to have done:

```
args=([fileData],)
```

Note the trailing comma. Had you done that, you would have seen this bug without adding the `Queue`.

Comment: You are correct about what I had originally, instead I should have just added the trailing comma.  I read time and time again that args was a `tuple`, and missed the trailing comma.  Instead I changed my arg to a list in frustration.  Thanks for the help.